# Taking Inputs from BufferReader

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I want to scan below input in from console but `BufferedReader` not scanning after 3 lines of input. please help .... 
Below is my Code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {
    root = new trienode();

    System.out.println("enter inputs");
    BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] s1 = s.readLine().split(" ");
    int  n = Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
    int  l = Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        String[] s2 = s.readLine().split(" ");
        String key=s2[0];
        int w=Integer.parseInt(s2[1]);
        //Insert(key , w);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        String s3 = s.readLine();
        if(search(s3)!=-1)
        System.out.println(search(s3));
    }

}
```

My Input is

```
2 1

abc 10

gef 9

ghi
```

Not able to scan `ghi`...... 
Please help

Comment: what does the function `search` do?  Need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: change for loop to `i<=n`, but still you will get `ArrayOutOfBoundException` since `s2[1]` will not have value when you read `ghi`

Comment: Are you sure that the 3rd and 4th line are separated by `\n` character

Comment: To debug, print n,l,key,w and check if they are correct

Comment: yes i beduged and value of n,l,key,w,are correct......

Comment: forget search(s3) function.... just want to store last line ghi in String s3.............

Answer (score 0):

Change `" "` to `"\\s+"` in split function.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    root = new trienode();

    System.out.println("enter inputs");
    BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] s1 = s.readLine().split("\\s+");
    int  n = Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
    int  l = Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        String[] s2 = s.readLine().split("\\s+");
        String key=s2[0];
        int w=Integer.parseInt(s2[1]);
        //Insert(key , w);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        String s3 = s.readLine();
        if(search(s3)!=-1)
        System.out.println(search(s3));
    }

}
```